# Swift specific notification observer initialization

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

While trying to use the new Swift NotificationCenter, I am trying to create observer objects as properties (against the classic Obj-C pattern of assigning observers to self):

```
private let keyboardWillShowObserver = {
    return NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil, using: self.keyboardWillShow(_:))
}()

private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    bottomVerticalSpaceConstraint.constant = 400
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error message, even though I have the member function part of the same class:

> Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> MyAwesomeViewController' has no member 'keyboardWillShow'

Answer (score 1):

HomeViewController   is your viewController

```
  private let keyboardWillShowObserver = {
        return NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil, using: { (Notification) in
            HomeViewController.keyboardWillShow (Notification)
        })

    }()

     static func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
       // bottomVerticalSpaceConstraint.constant = 400
    }
```

Comment: Making the method static avoids the error, but then I can't access the instance properties...

Answer (score 1):

Since your `keyboardWillShowObserver` is not lazy, it's closure will be executed during instance initialization of `MyAwesomeViewController`. As far as I understand, that means `self` will be interpreted as `MyAwesomeViewController` class but not the instance of class.

There is an easy way to fix this error: make `private lazy var keyboardWillShowObserver` so the closure will be executed on instance *after* it will be completely initialized.

Comment: Making it lazy will be against the observer pattern, am I correct? Because without explicitly accessing the `keyboardWillShowObserver` the notification will never be assigned.